# Error registering rosandroid client

Tags: java, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
i'm trying to create a rosjava client to connect to a c++ service, but when the client is being registered the following warning is showed.

```
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335): An exception was thrown by a user handler while handling an exception event ([id: 0x406087c0] EXCEPTION: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335): org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler.exceptionCaught(ConnectionTrackingHandler.java:81) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:533) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:157) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:102) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:55) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:642) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:205) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:230) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:183) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:105) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClientManager.connect(TcpClientManager.java:71) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.service.DefaultServiceClient.connect(DefaultServiceClient.java:137) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.service.ServiceFactory.newClient(ServiceFactory.java:148) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.newServiceClient(DefaultNode.java:365) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.newServiceClient(DefaultNode.java:372) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.android.android_tutorial_pubsub.EnviaDadosClient.onStart(EnviaDadosClient.java:32) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:506) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:503) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.concurrent.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:43) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop.run(CancellableLoop.java:56) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335): Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SocketChannelImpl.validateAddress(SocketChannelImpl.java:513) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:174) 
02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:139) 02-28 10:28:06.275: W/DefaultChannelPipeline(335):  ... 20 more
```

followed by this error:

```
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-4
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335): org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Connection exception: ricardo-Inspiron-5423:48559
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:117)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClientManager.connect(TcpClientManager.java:71)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.service.DefaultServiceClient.connect(DefaultServiceClient.java:137)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.service.ServiceFactory.newClient(ServiceFactory.java:148)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.newServiceClient(DefaultNode.java:365)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.newServiceClient(DefaultNode.java:372)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.android.android_tutorial_pubsub.EnviaDadosClient.onStart(EnviaDadosClient.java:32)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:506)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:503)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.concurrent.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:43)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop.run(CancellableLoop.java:56)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SocketChannelImpl.validateAddress(SocketChannelImpl.java:513)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:174)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:139)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:102)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:55)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:642)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:205)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:230)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:183)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:105)
02-28 10:28:06.295: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 13 more
```

Anyone has any idea of how to solve these problems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56613/error-registering-rosandroid-client/) by [Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4287/rocha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-03-02**:
Please provide some more context. Code and especially network settings. See your error "Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException"

**Comment by [paulofinseca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4259/paulofinseca/) on 2013-03-02**:
Same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already solved the problem... it was problem of configuration of hosts on emulator

To solve the problem follow these steps...

With the emulator arleady opened, run:

```
cd adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools/

./adb -s  emulator-5554 remount
```

To remount the filesystem so its not read only and you’ll be able to change the hosts file.

Then run:

```
./adb -s  emulator-5554 pull /etc/hosts
```

This gets the current hosts file from the device. Edit it in whatever text editor, it’s been pulled to the current working dir.
I used gedit.
gedit hosts

and add the following line

```
10.0.2.2   machineName
```

in my case

```
10.0.2.2   rocha
```

Finally run:

```
./adb -s  emulator-5554 push hosts /etc/hosts
```

---

Originally posted by [Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4287/rocha/) with karma: 26 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulofinseca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4259/paulofinseca/) on 2013-03-05**:
Not worked for me :(
Can you run without problems on your smartphone?